# IOS to C# what is equivalent of id<>

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I got a IOS code to rewrite in c# that has this `id<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> gestureDelegate;`

How can i rewrite this in c#?

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> gestureDelegate;
```

Actually I declare it like `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate gestureDelegate;` but is it right?
If i understand it right, `id` is like `var` in C#? 
If that's so how can i declare it as class parameters?

Comment: yes it is equivalent .

Comment: Is @property means that is a static parameters?

Comment: property declared because we want this variable outside class so. yes it keyword for define property in objective C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C# `interface` is like `protocol` in Objective-C, `id<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>` means the object implements the methods defined in `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`. So the same thing in C# could be (main idea, not tested in IDE):

```
interface UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
   public bool gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(UIGestureRecognizer gestureRecognizer);
}

class Example {
   public UIGestureRecognizerDelegate gestureDelegate; //the equivalent
}
```

And a class which conforms to the interface:

```
public class ExampleViewController:UIViewController,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
   var example = Example();

   public ExampleViewController() {
       this.example.gestureDelegate = this;
   }

   //implements the methods of interface UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
   public bool gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(UIGestureRecognizer gestureRecognizer) {
       //......
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. You are able to inherit from only 1 class, and many interfaces. I updated the answer for your information.

Comment: Good answer :) For completeness, I would only add that the `weak` qualifier, in the original Objective-C property declaration, makes no sense in C# since it uses a *garbage collection* to manage memory (and not a reference counting system as Objective-C does).

Comment: @PauloMattos, thanks for improving the English express, ;)